# Profiling intel mkl functions with valgrind and gprof

Tags: c, profiling, valgrind, intel-mkl, gprof

I want to profile several different functions, and started therefore with two simple functions:

```
void expVec(const int a_len, const double *a, double *b)
{
    vdExp(a_len, a, b);//Using the vectorial exp-function from the mkl library
}
```

and

```
void expVec_sample(const int len, const double *a, double *b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)//Serial execution
        b[i] = exp(a[i]);
}
```

I call them with

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    expVec(len, a, c);
    expVec_sample(len, a, b);
}
```

and compile the program with

```
gcc-5 main.c speed_test.c -o main -I/opt/intel/mkl/include -pg -g -DMKL_ILP64 -mavx -msse4.2 -msse3 -msse2 -m64 -flto -march=native -funroll-loops -std=gnu99 -Wl,--start-group /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl -lfftw3 -lfftw3_threads
```

I am using most of the switches due to copy- and paste from another project (where I will ultimately use the results from the profiling).
Now I get (when trying to measure the performance of both functions) the result in gprof:

```
index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]     35.6    2.45    0.00                 mkl_vml_kernel_dError [1]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[2]     33.4    2.29    0.00                 mkl_vml_kernel_dExp_E9HAynn [2]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[3]     12.9    0.89    0.00                 mkl_vml_kernel_GetMode [3]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.64    0.00   10000/10000       main [5]
[4]      9.3    0.64    0.00   10000         expVec_sample [4]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[5]      9.3    0.00    0.64                 main [5]
                0.64    0.00   10000/10000       expVec_sample [4]
                0.00    0.00   10000/10000       expVec [9]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           fill [10]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[6]      7.0    0.48    0.00                 vdexp_cout_rare [6]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[7]      1.4    0.10    0.00                 mkl_vml_kernel_SetMode [7]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[8]      0.4    0.03    0.00                 mkl_vml_kernel_zError [8]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00   10000/10000       main [5]
[9]      0.0    0.00    0.00   10000         expVec [9]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [5]
[10]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         fill [10]
-----------------------------------------------
```

which already shows me that error handling in the mkl takes a large amount of time. When I try to profile it with valgrind, I get:

```
==29598== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x40ea75.
==29598==    at 0x40EA75: mkl_vml_kernel_dExp_E9HAynn (in /home/roland/Dokumente/MA/gnlse/c-ext_test/speed_test/main)
==29598==    by 0x40220D: vdExp (in /home/roland/Dokumente/MA/gnlse/c-ext_test/speed_test/main)
==29598==    by 0x401D0B: expVec (speed_test.c:21)
==29598==    by 0x401BC5: main (main.c:18)
==29598== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==29598== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==29598== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==29598==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==29598==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==29598== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==29598==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==29598==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==29598== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==29598== probably kill your program.
==29598== 
==29598== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==29598==  Illegal opcode at address 0x40EA75
==29598==    at 0x40EA75: mkl_vml_kernel_dExp_E9HAynn (in /home/roland/Dokumente/MA/gnlse/c-ext_test/speed_test/main)
==29598==    by 0x40220D: vdExp (in /home/roland/Dokumente/MA/gnlse/c-ext_test/speed_test/main)
==29598==    by 0x401D0B: expVec (speed_test.c:21)
==29598==    by 0x401BC5: main (main.c:18)
==29598== 
==29598== Events    : Ir
==29598== Collected : 530647
==29598== 
==29598== I   refs:      530,647
Unvalid machine command (Memory dump written)
```

What generates those errors, and how can I profile both functions in a useful way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about *valgrind*, but as you can see *gprof* is not going to give you useful information. For example, it looks like it spends a large fraction of time in error handling. Doing what? For what purpose?

*Maybe* it just goes in there and comes right out again, and your vectors are so small that processing them takes so little time that it's about the same as that error routine doing nothing.

[*Here is a ton of discussion about things like that, and what to do about it.*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)